# resolve npm module dependencies

Tags: css, node.js, webpack, vue.js

For a project, I'm using a library that I have built in order to share Vue components across the different applications.

So I import my component library as a npm module and I added it to the application package.json and that works fine.

The problem is that when I try to import something in the single component in the components library the application can't solve the dependencies of that component.

e.g component in the component library:

```
  <template>
    <!-- my html -->
  </template>
  </script>
    // my script
  </script>

  <style scoped>
  // here I import the basic style for the component:
  @import "../../assets/base";
```

in the application package.json I have:

```
  "components": "git+ssh://git@git.xxxxx.com:xxxxx/xxxxx/my-library.git#development",
```

and then I use the component normally in my project like this:

```
  import MyComponent from "./components/MyComponent.vue";
```

The component library works fine, but when I import the component in the application I get the following error from webpack:

```
This dependency was not found:

* -!../../../../css-loader/index.js?sourceMap!../../assets/base in ./~/css-loader?sourceMap!./~/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-28803148","scoped":true,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./~/components/src/core/MyComponent.vue
To install it, you can run: npm install --save -!../../../../css-loader/index.js?sourceMap!../../assets/base
```

Of course if I substitute the @import with the actual css needed everything works fine. How can I make this configuration works?

Comment: Have you installed and configured css-loader?  That is what the error is referring to.

Comment: Why are you using a relative path to the component? It's supposed to be a in `node_modules` and the import would be `components/MyComponent.vue`. Also the CSS import is `../../assets/base`, that's two directories up and if it's in `MyComponent.vue` it means that it's looking for it outside the module and that won't work well. Was that intentional?

Answer (score 0):

My bad, the error was simply not adding lang="scss" in the style declaration of the component:

```
  <style scoped>
```

this should be:

```
  <style scoped lang="scss">
```